# jQuery save append option value

Tags: jquery

How do i Pass data from jQuery Ajax to PHP option value and set the saved option as selected.

jQuery

```
var socialicons = ['Facebook', 'Twitter', 'LinkedIN'];
$.each(socialicons, function(val, text) {
    $('select').append( $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text) )
});
```

PHP

```
<select name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][url]" id="'. $id .'['.$order.'][url]"> 
$socialicons = array ('facebook' => 'Facebook', 'twitter' => 'Twitter', 'linkedin' => 'linkedIN') 

foreach ($socialicons as $socialicon) { <option value="'.$socialicon.'" ' . selected($data[$id][$order]['url'], $socialicon, false) . ' />'.$socialicon.'</option> } </select>
```

E.G

```
<select>
<option value="Facebook" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="Twitter"></option>
<option value="LinkeIN"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Which `option` do you want to be selected? You're adding three...

Comment: what is `saved` and saved where?

Comment: The one i selected from the dropdown. Getting a PHP variable in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your php variable for selected option is called $selected_option

```
  ...
  $('select').append( $('<option></option>').addClass(val).val(val).html(text) ); 
  ...
  $('select option').removeAttr('selected');
  $('.<?php echo $selected_option ?>').attr('selected','true');
```

your adding a class with the name of the option to the option element, so you can easily mark it as selected by passing in the php selected option variable.

Comment: To be more clear here is my php code: 
<select name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][url]" id="'. $id .'['.$order.'][url]">

                $socialicons =  array ('facebook' => 'Facebook', 'twitter' => 'Twitter', 'linkedin' => 'linkedIN')

                foreach ($socialicons as $socialicon)  {


<option value="'.$socialicon.'" ' . selected($data[$id][$order]['url'], $socialicon, false) . ' />'.$socialicon.'</option>

                } 
</select>

Comment: cant read this code sorry, i dont know if the format was changed but this is no php code. Maybe you edit your question with the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Thanks to all.

```
 var socialicons ='["Facebook","Twitter","linkedIN"]';
                var parsedjson = $.parseJSON(socialicons);
                $.each( parsedjson , function( index, item ) {
                $("<option/>",{value:item,text:item}).appendTo(".select");
                });
```